# Cannot read the next data row for the dataset SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: java, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to run a report with a multi-value parameter.  It's a really simple case, the query basically looks like this:

```
SELECT COLNAME
FROM TABLE
WHERE (COLNAME IN (@PARAM))
```

From within Visual Studio, I can run the report no questions asked.  However, once it's uploaded to the report server and called from our web app, I get the following error:

```
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed
when converting the nvarchar value '104274,104264' to data type int.
```

Ok, so it's pretty obvious what the issue is.  The parameters are not being recognized by SSRS as a CSV list of parameters, but rather as one string.  I noticed if I pass the values into the param manually with a linebreak inbetween them instead of a comma, it works.  But the request URL in both cases is exactly the same:

```
broken case: POST /ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2feval_multi&rs%3aCommand=Render&evalID=104274%2c104264&userID=472 HTTP/1.1\\r\\n
working case:POST /ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2feval_multi&rs%3aCommand=Render&evalID=104274%2c104264&userID=472 HTTP/1.1\\r\\n
```

This is being called from our Java web app which returns an HttpServletResponse object using a GET request to SSRS.  How do I get SSRS to understand that these parameters are multivalued and not just one string when coming from Java (yes, the parameter is specified as multi-value in visual studio)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.  Rather then sending a string to the server via ajax, I sent it an array of strings.  Seems like SSRS was able to understand that better (even though the get request is still the same, go figure).